# Calculus help on limits (epsilon delta)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

I know the definition and how to prove some limits, but this is a monstrosity. I did some writing but I am still confused. I cannot express for n here because I cannot algebraically manipulate the expression. Please help and please if you can explain easily, it's my third week of freshman year :)

> [image]

My **Attempt**:
[image]

Comment: You need to make a more serious effort, even if it is just the beginning of your studies. Surely you should have learned in class (or by reading the homework question) what to write instead of $|n-\infty|<\delta$ (which is total nonsense).

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that I should find an N value instead of writing n-inf but I cannot algebraically manipulate the huge a) fraction in order to express as n

Comment: But at least start by writing out correct statements, with English words, and in complete sentence form, of what you need to show. Then you'll need to do some algebra to reach your goal. I would recommend you start by solving the limits *without* any $N$ and $\epsilon$, just so you realize what the algebra needs to be.

Comment: Still unclear, if I was able to solve for limit this whole fraction I would easily express it as a relationship of n and epsilon, but I cannot solve the limit because I cannot algebraically simplify it. I would really appreciate some help, you are criticizing the "nonsense" that I wrote, but I don't want to copy the work, I want help to understand it, If I just wanted to copy it I would ask my peers to send me their work. No offense intended, but I came here for help, not a lecture.

Comment: I've taught this material for over 40 years to hundreds and hundreds of students, so you'll have to trust me that my "lecture" was in fact help. You *must* start by writing correct definitions and sentences that make sense, or else you will never understand anything. But feel free to ignore me.

Comment: Sure, but people down here at least share with hints, none of them could completely make me comprehend the problem but at least I get something, I don't think that it would be so difficult for a 40 year professional to help me solve or give hints (not that anybody has to), instead of saying obvious things like "express your statements in English", I know the definition I do not need to write it down, I have solved the number b) already. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a general advice, when you have a  messy expressions such as a), what  you want to do is to find an upper bound, that is, a new expression that is always greater or equal to  your original expression, obviously you want your new expression to be nicer than the original one  and then you prove that your new expression converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for (a): the numerator is always between $1$ and $5$ (why?). So you just need to choose $N$ large enough so that for all $n \ge N$ we have $\frac{5}{4n+\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon$.

Hint for (b): $\frac{9n-2}{6n-1}-\frac{3}{2}=  - \frac{1}{12n-2}$.

Comment: I think you meant $5/(4n+\sqrt{n})\lt\epsilon$

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks for the correction

Comment: Can you help me? I understand that sine is a function from -1 to 1 and if you multiply it by 2 you get -2 to 2 and adding 3 shifts the function upwards to 1 to 5. How did you get the 5 in the numerator? How can you so easily pick a value for N? After your hint I got 5/(4n + sqrt n) < E ==> (4n + sqrt n)/5 > 1/E ==> n > (5/e - sqrt n)/4, but I still don't understand how you got that 5 in the numerator

Comment: Thank you so much, only your hint helped me.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For the first, use the fact that

$$|sin(X)|\le 1$$
and
$$n\ge \sqrt{n}$$
to get

$$|u_n|\le \frac{5}{5\sqrt{n}}$$
and look for $N$ such that

$$n>N \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$$
or
$$n> \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$$